# how to let flask-sqlalchemy's query object select columns ( or say fields )?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I met some problem that wired me the whole day. I'm using flask/flask-sqlalchemy/postgresql, and I want to do this:

```
published_sites = msg_published.query \
            .filter( and_(*filter_clause) ) \
            .group_by( msg_published.site_id ) \
            .order_by( order_clause ) \
            .paginate( page_no, per_page, error_out = False )
```

but in mysql, it is OK, and in postgresql it is wrong and ask for the other fields besides site_id either in a group by clause or in a aggregation function, I know that postgresql is stricter on SQL than mysql , so I must select the site_id in the query object of msg_published, but in pure sqlalchemy I can do like this:

```
published_sites = session.query( msg_published.site_id ) \
            .filter( and_(*filter_clause) ) \
            .group_by( msg_published.site_id ) \
            .order_by( order_clause ) \
            .paginate( page_no, per_page, error_out = False )
```

and in flask-sqlalchemy, how to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there.  to do in PostgreSQL what MySQL allows requires a subselect.

```
published_sites_ids = session.query( msg_published.site_id ) \
            .filter( and_(*filter_clause) ) \
            .group_by( msg_published.site_id ) \
            .order_by( order_clause ) \
            .paginate( page_no, per_page, error_out = False )

published_sites = session.query(msg_published) \
                         .filter(msg_published.id.in_(published_sites_ids))
```